# Button inside array mapping in React

Tags: reactjs, arrays, button, mapping, increment

I have created two buttons inside a mapped array elements with the function to decrement and increment a value, but clicking on one button increments all the other button values

code below

```
const [cart, setCart] = useState(0)
    function addCart() {
        setCart(cart + 1)
    }
    function removeCart() {
        if (cart > 0) {
            setCart(cart - 1)
        }
    }

return(
<div>
{details.category_dishes.map((item) => (
<div>
<ButtonGroup >
    <Button id={item.dish_id} style={{ borderTopLeftRadius: '50%', borderBottomLeftRadius: '50%' }} variant='success' onClick={removeCart}>-</Button>
    <span className='bg-success p-2'>{cart}</span>
    <Button style={{ borderTopRightRadius: '50%', borderBottomRightRadius: '50%' }} variant='success' onClick={addCart}>+</Button>
</ButtonGroup>
</div>
)

</div>
)
```

i want only the respective value two be changing when the button is clicked

code below

```
const [cart, setCart] = useState(0)
    function addCart() {
        setCart(cart + 1)
    }
    function removeCart() {
        if (cart > 0) {
            setCart(cart - 1)
        }
    }

return(
<div>
{details.category_dishes.map((item) => (
<div>
<ButtonGroup >
    <Button id={item.dish_id} style={{ borderTopLeftRadius: '50%', borderBottomLeftRadius: '50%' }} variant='success' onClick={removeCart}>-</Button>
    <span className='bg-success p-2'>{cart}</span>
    <Button style={{ borderTopRightRadius: '50%', borderBottomRightRadius: '50%' }} variant='success' onClick={addCart}>+</Button>
</ButtonGroup>
</div>
)

</div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why clicking on one button increments all the other button values is because they are all referring to the same state value cart. To fix this issue, you need to create a separate state value for each item in the mapped array. One way to achieve this is by creating an object to hold the state values for each item using their dish_id as keys. Here's how you can modify your code to fix this issue:

```
const [cart, setCart] = useState({});

function addCart(id) {
  setCart((prevCart) => ({
    ...prevCart,
    [id]: (prevCart[id] || 0) + 1
  }));
}

function removeCart(id) {
  if (cart[id] > 0) {
    setCart((prevCart) => ({
      ...prevCart,
      [id]: prevCart[id] - 1
    }));
  }
}

return (
  <div>
    {details.category_dishes.map((item) => (
      <div key={item.dish_id}>
        <ButtonGroup>
          <Button
            style={{ borderTopLeftRadius: '50%', borderBottomLeftRadius: '50%' }}
            variant='success'
            onClick={() => removeCart(item.dish_id)}
          >
            -
          </Button>
          <span className='bg-success p-2'>
            {cart[item.dish_id] || 0}
          </span>
          <Button
            style={{ borderTopRightRadius: '50%', borderBottomRightRadius: '50%' }}
            variant='success'
            onClick={() => addCart(item.dish_id)}
          >
            +
          </Button>
        </ButtonGroup>
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: is says "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."